# switch statement for a joint of different enum classes in Java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

**I have two enum classes, say Enum1 and Enum2:**

```
enum Enum1 {ONE, TWO, THREE}
enum Enum2 {FOUR, FIVE}
```

**and I have a method like this:**

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> method (E arg) {
    switch (arg) {    // Here is the compile error -- Cannot switch
                      // on a value of type E. Only convertible int
                      // values, strings or enum variables are permitted

                      // (And of course, all the cases are incorrect
                      // because the enum set is unknown)
        case ONE:
            // do something
        case TWO:
            // do something
        case THREE:
            // do something
        case FOUR:
            // do something
        case FIVE:
            // do something
        default:
            // do something
    }
}
```

---

### So is it possible to switch a value of a generic enum type?

---

There is one way to change it to strings (only works in JDK7):

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> method (E arg) {
    switch (arg.name()) {
        case "ONE":
            // do something
        case "TWO":
            // do something
        case "THREE":
            // do something
        case "FOUR":
            // do something
        case "FIVE":
            // do something
        default:
            // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any Enum documentation?

Comment: Even if it would be possible, the two enums aren't related to each other. You can't test an Enum1 against a case FOUR or FIVE value. So your code doesn't make sense written in this way.

Comment: @Heisenbug, Well, I know. I will not do this in a real project, I'm just trying out the language. Because all the enum types are implicitly derived from java.lang.Enum, so I think there should be some generic relationships between different enum types and I tried that. So in JDK7, there is a way to do that -- switching on arg.name() and quoting everything in case statements (the name() gets a string representing exactly what it is declared in its enum declaration) -- of course it's some trivial findings, but just for fun!

Comment: @shuangwhywhy: my comment wasn't intended to be critic, sorry. I was just pointing out that. Always pleased to see people experimenting with the language ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying. For one thing, an `enum` switch is actually a shorthand for a switch on the `ordinal()` of the enum. So even if you could get the switch to recognize your "joint enum" type, the statement has duplicate `case` branches. (For instance, `ONE` and `FOUR` both have ordinal 0.)

One approach might be to move the action into the enums themselves. You can then have each `enum` type implement a common interface:

```
interface Actor {
    void doSomething();
}

enum Enum1 implements Actor {
    ONE {
        public void doSomething() { . . . }
    },
    TWO {
        public void doSomething() { . . . }
    },
    THREE {
        public void doSomething() { . . . }
    }
}

enum Enum2 implements Actor {
    FOUR {
        public void doSomething() { . . . }
    },
    FIVE {
        public void doSomething() { . . . }
    }
}
```

Then you could implement your method to simply delegate the processing to the actor:

```
public void method(Actor actor) {
    if (actor == null) {
         // default action
    } else {
        actor.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to cast the enum to a specific type before the switch statement (and therefore have a separate switch statement for each type). THat said, this isn't the best of ideas. It is likely that you will find a better solution by refactoring the code so that you do not need to do this.

Comment: Yes, I know. I will not do this in a real project, I'm just trying out the language. Because all the enum types are implicitly derived from java.lang.Enum, so I think there should be some generic relationships between different enum types and I tried that. So in JDK7, there is a way to do that -- switching on arg.name() and quoting everything in case statements (the name() gets a string representing exactly what it is declared in its enum declaration) -- of course it's some trivial findings, but just for fun!

Answer (score 0):

The switch you mention does obviously not work.

I have a (quite weird) substitution: create a "helper enum" which contains all values listed, and have a `Map<Request<Enum<?>, HelperEnum>`, like this:

```
private enum HelperEnum {
       ONE(Enum1.ONE),
       TWO(Enum1.TWO),
       THREE(Enum1.THREE),
       FOUR(Enum2.FOUR),
       FIVE(Enum2.FIVE);

       private Enum<?> source;

       private HelperEnum(Enum<?> source) {
           this.source = source;
       }

       private static Map<Enum<?>, HelperEnum> map;

       public static HelperEnum lookUp(Enum<?> source) {
           if (map == null) {
               map = Arrays.stream(HelperEnum.values())
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.source, x -> x));
           }
           return map.get(source);
       }
```

(untested!)

This way you can then do

```
switch(HelperEnum.lookUp(a_request)){
    case ONE: ....
    case TWO: ....
    case THREE: ....
    case FOUR: ....
    case FIVE: ....
}
```

(analogous version first published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891051/296974))

It would be helpful have a common interface implemented by the enums in question, but this one would probably work as well.